# cshell tab completion , case insensitive

Tags: autocomplete, csh

For  C Shell is there a  way to make tab completion  for commands, files etc. case insensitive?

I saw the `complete=enhance` variable, but that is only for tcsh, not csh.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
set autolist = ambiguous 
set complete = enhance
```

Comment: `set complete = enhance` completes `.` as anything. Without it its case sensitive. I'm irrationally annoyed by this.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more verbose answer for the uber newbs:

Ratheesh Pai's answer is correct, but if you want the settings to persist, you want to write the commands to your `.cshrc` file. This file is executed any time you open a shell (assuming the `.cshrc` file is in your home directory. Think of the `.cshrc` file as a settings file - you add whatever personal preferences you want into it...

Here's how to setup tab completion:

```
cd ~
vim .cshrc
```

## Insert in the two lines below into `.cshrc`

```
set autolist = ambiguous 
set complete = enhance
```

Then quit VIM.

Last, either re-open your shell (or source the `.cshrc` file):

```
source ./.cshrc
```

Then give it a shot, you should be able to case-insensitive tab complete.